# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager' while attempting to activate ApplicationSignInManager

Tags: c#, owin, identity

I'm using vnext with identity 2 and I get the error

> Unable to resolve service for type `Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager`

while attempting to activate `ApplicationSignInManager`.

In my `Startup.cs` I have :

```
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int>, ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

In my `ApplicationSignInManager.cs` class

```
public sealed class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int>
{   
    UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> _userManager { get; }
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int> _signInManager { get; }

    public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> _userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) : base(_userManager, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication)
    {
       UserManager = _userManager;
    }
}
```

I've tried many different approaches and I can't get by this hurdle.